# Can't run flutter build from Jenkins

Tags: flutter, jenkins, build, pipeline

I tried to run a flutter build from jenkins using the following pipeline code :

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                bat 'C:\\path_to_doc\\flutter_dev\\flutter\\bin\\flutter.bat build web -t "C:\\path_to_doc\\lib\\src\\main\\main.dart"'
            }
        }
    }
    post{
        always {
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'C:\\path_to_doc\\build\\web\\index.html', fingerprint: true, followSymlinks: false
        }
    }
}
```

I got this error in jenkins :

[image]

I tried to write the flutter build code in a bat file in the root of my flutter project, and then execute this file on the pipeline code, got the same error.

What is the correct way to proceed to avoid this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins has a habit of reverting to the initial workspace directory for each separate command. Try setting the directory after your `steps{` line:

```
dir('C:\\path_to_doc\\flutter_dev\\flutter\\bin\\') {
    bat 'flutter.bat build web -t "C:\\path_to_doc\\lib\\src\\main\\main.dart"'
}
```

This will ensure that your script will run in this location. So if your `pubspec.yaml` is in this location, it should be able to find it. In any case, this is a problem with the directory, so if this doesn't work, some manual debugging would be necessary to see what went wrong.